# InnoSetup: Can I call a custom method from a pre-processor directive

Tags: inno-setup

I have a [code] section which defines a method I wrote, let's say it's foo.

I want to test the result of foo in a pre-processor directive, like this:

```
#if foo()
...
#endif
```

But the InnoSetup complains that it doesn't see foo().  Can the preprocessor call user defined methods??

I know foo is visible in general, because I can refer to foo in other places in the script, with no problem.

Michael

Answer (score 2):

No. The preprocessor runs just before the installer is built, to *pre-process* the script file. Everything is done at the time the installer is being constructed (built), not when the installer is executed.